# Best way to use sounds in gameScene

Tags: swift, audio, avplayer, skaction, skaudionode

What is the best way to add sounds into a game. I've done some research, tried everything and all methods seem to have something wrong. For example:

1. using SKAction.playFileNamed() has memory leaks, eventually will crash the app after extensive use.
2. the workaround for that will be so use SKAudioNode with SKAction. Problem with this is that the app crashes when you plug-in headphones
3. use AVPlayer. Problem with this is that it makes your app very very slow.

So these being said, how am I supposed to add sounds into my game and avoid all the problems above?

Thanks

Comment: are these issues with AVPlayer or just how swift uses it ?  are you targeting osx or mobile ?   I have used OpenAL on iOS to great effect with no lag

Comment: AVPlayer, mobile iOS. how did u use it? thanks